# Calculate rectangle's points from diagonal in 3D

Tags: c#, geometry, rectangles, plane, diagonal

I know 3 points in a 3D plane. Two points are the ends of a diagonal and an other one which is random point on the plane. How can I calculate the two other points of a rectangle from the known diagonal line? (Later I will use the points to calculate the perimeter of the rectangle in C#.)

Comment: Isn't this more related to MathOverflow?

Comment: Please ask this at the more related TaxonomyOverflow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single right answer. All you can calculate using a diagonal and a random point on the plane is a whole sets of possible answers.
Imagine rotating the diagonal to create a circle - now every second line inscribed in that circle and going through the center can be the second diagonal. The only limit is your third point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the  end points of the diagonal, you can calculate the length of the diagonal; from there you can determine the rectangle side length; having  diagonal coordinates and the side length, you can determine the other two points of the rectangle using add/subtraction.

Comment: So how can the rectangle side length be determined from the diagonal length?

Comment: side1*side1+side2*side2=diag*diag

Comment: Say I have a diagonal length of "5". Are the two sides ("3" and "4") or ("4" and "3"). Or even ("almost 0" and "nearly 5")?

Comment: @ Hans: Unless you can check against that 3rd point on the plane( lets say for  example that 3rd point has to be inside/outside of the rectangle) he'll have indeed 2 solutions

Comment: That 3rd point is just "on the plane", not a corner (which *would* decide the rectangle), or even "inside the rect".